# Displaying Html.ListBoxFor for association class with one additional property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, razor

**EDIT and partial answer:** I don't know how to display multiple columns but If it is not the case You must override ToString in Call class.

---

I have a class `Person`(they receive calls):

```
 public class Person {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Call> ReceivedCalls { get; set; }
    }
```

a class `ApplicationUser` (they make calls):

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser {
        public virtual ICollection<Call> MadeCalls { get; set; }
 }
```

and a association class between them which is `Call`:

```
 public class Call {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Person Callee { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser Caller { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; } //Additional Attribute
    }
```

They work together great in database. But I have a trouble using `@Html.ListBoxFor` method to display a ListBox where in every row there will be information who called and when: `Caller.UserName | Call.TimeStamp` for every call received(by Person).

I want to display those information in Razor View strongly typed against:

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.Person
```

I have tried this:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.ReceivedCalls, new MultiSelectList(Model.ReceivedCalls, "TimeStamp" ), new {Multiple = "multiple"})
```

it is being translated(output HTML) to:

```
<select Multiple="multiple" id="ReceivedCalls" multiple="multiple" name="ReceivedCalls"><option selected="selected">System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Call_2FC3E1C25C19BA21E6B64CAB2894602434775435359AAB76E58C6F8411451A49</option>
<option selected="selected">System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Call_2FC3E1C25C19BA21E6B64CAB2894602434775435359AAB76E58C6F8411451A49</option>
</select>
```

and it looks like:

[image]

**Question:** How to display ListBox where in every row there will be information who called and when: `Caller.UserName | Call.TimeStamp` displayed for every call received(by Person).

---

### **EDIT:**

There were some syntax errors:

```
        // Create collection of anonymous objects (adjust format to suit your needs)
        var receivedCalls = person.ReceivedCalls.Select(c => new {
            ID = c.Id,
            DisplayName = string.Format("{0}: {1:D}", c.Caller.UserName, c.TimeStamp)
        });
        // Initialise view model
        PersonVM model = new PersonVM();
        // Map properties from person to model

        // Assign select list
        model.CallList = new MultiSelectList(receivedCalls, "ID", "DisplaName");
```

View:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.ReceivedCalls, new MultiSelectList(Model.ReceivedCalls))
```

---

The result is exacly the same if I just override ToString in `Call`:

```
   public override string ToString() {
            if (Caller != null)
                return Caller.UserName + " called at " + TimeStamp;
            return "called at " + TimeStamp;
        }

@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.ReceivedCalls, new MultiSelectList(Model.ReceivedCalls, "TimeStamp"), new { Multiple = "multiple", style = "width: 100%;" })
```

So I think it still relies on ToString.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a view model to display and bind you properties

View model

```
public class PersonVM
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public int[] ReceivedCalls { get; set; } // this will bind to the selected calls
  public MultiSelectList CallList { get; set; } // to display the calls   
}
```

Controller

```
// Create collection of anonymous objects (adjust format to suit your needs)
var receivedCalls = person.ReceivedCalls.Select(c => new 
{
  ID = c.ID,
  DisplayName = string.Format("{0}: {1:D}", c.Callee.UserName, c.TimeStamp)
}
// Initialise view model
PersonVM model = new PersonVM();
// Map properties from person to model
...
// Assign select list
model.CallList  = new MultiSelectList(receivedCalls , "ID", "DisplaName");
return View(model);
```

View

```
@model YourAssembly.PersonVM
....
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.ReceivedCalls, Model.CallList)
```

**Edit**

Based on OP's requirement that the collection of recent calls is for display only (not for editing), adjust the view to use an unordered list (based on OP's model, not the view model suggested above)

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.Person
....
<ul>
  @foreach(var call in Model.ReceivedCalls)
  {
    <li>@call</li> // this will use the .ToString() method
  }
</ul>
```

Then just style the elements as required, for example to set a fixed height and make it scrollable with no bullets

```
<style>
  ul {
    height:60px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
  }
  li {
    list-style:none;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Please look at my edit. There were some syntax errors I fix them but maybe broke something else. I get the same results as I just leave overriden ToString. Thank you.

Comment: What syntax errors? Did you do what I showed? Your edit has `@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.ReceivedCalls, new MultiSelectList(Model.ReceivedCalls))` but it should be `@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.ReceivedCalls, Model.CallList)`. `CallList` is already a `MultiSelectList` so you don't create it again.

Comment: Also its a little unclear exactly what you are tying to achieve here by using a `<select>` element. Are you wanting the user to be able to select some `Calls` and save those selections to the database, or do you just want to display the collection of the persons `Calls` on the page (in which case using a `<select>` is not appropriate)

Comment: I want only display recent calls in scrollable container that's why I have chosen ListBox (analogy to JList and ListSomething in Android). Is opposite oreder is easy achievable(last call first on the list)?

Comment: In that case, there is no need to use a `<select>` control, which is for posting back data. I'll update answer shortly.

Comment: I just wanted to add that I fixed the order: `@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.ReceivedCalls, new MultiSelectList(Model.ReceivedCalls.OrderByDescending(call => call.TimeStamp), "TimeStamp"), new { Multiple = "multiple", style = "width: 500px;" })
`

Comment: Yes, but you should not be using `@ListBoxFor()`. In my edited answer, you can use `@foreach(var call in Model.ReceivedCalls.OrderByDescending(c => c.TimeStamp)) {..` if you want to display in order.